# getting error when run mongodump into powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, error-handling, mongodump

But its working in normal powershell and its dumping.I need to dump it from powershell ISE and I used to find error by `try/catch`

```
$database = "youtube"
$backupPath = 'C:\workspace\mongobackup' 
$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'   
Try{
   "backup initiated"
   $x=mongodump -v --db $database --out $backupPath 
   "backup completed "
}
catch{     
  write-host $_
}
```

Here is my code , this will come after running 2023-01-20T14:02:17.545+0530 dumping up to 1 collections in parallel.

Comment: if copy/pasting the code in PS working, then there is no reason that it wont work with ISE unless you are using x86 version of it. Better script it as .ps1 and call the script. That is the best thing to do.

Comment: in command line and powershell the mongodump command is working. then i only ran mongodump command in ise then the error was                                                                            PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> mongodump
mongodump : 2023-01-22T17:03:51.997+0530 writing admin.system.version to 
dump\admin\system.version.bson
At line:1 char:1
+ mongodump
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (2023-01-22T17:0...em.version.bson 
   :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError